# Can't get event.target in handle event function when upload image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

So here is my handle onChange function when I upload a file

```
    handleLoadAvatar(e) {
    if (e && e.target.files) {
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      if (file && file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
          const image = new Image();
          image.src = e.target.result; //get null here
          image.onload = () => {
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = env.avatar_size;
            canvas.height = env.avatar_size;
            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0, env.avatar_size, env.avatar_size);
            const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
            this.setState({ previewSrc: dataUrl, canvasAvatar: canvas, enableUpload: false });
          };
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    }
  }
```

These codes used to work perfectly until recently I've got this warning:

> Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If
>   you're seeing this, you're accessing the property target on a
>   released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must
>   keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist()

I tried to put `event.persist()` but still didn't work.

Comment: `e` is the event which has been fired by the file input element. Your `onload` handler of the `FileReader` doesn't use its event argument.

Comment: I've changed my onload handler into:
reader.onload = ((e) => {
          ...
        })(e);
Doesn't help :(

Comment: That's an IIFE where you pass the outer event object into the IIFE and assign the return value of this call (`undefined`) as the `onload` handler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event object `e` in `image.src = e.target.result` is the event that has been fired by the input element.

Either you have to use the event element passed to the `onload` handler:

```
reader.onload = (loadEvent) => {
    //...
    image.src = loadEvent.target.result;
    //...
}
```

or the reader object directly:

```
reader.onload = (loadEvent) => {
    //...
    image.src = reader.result;
    //...
}
```

Comment: that solved my problem, thanks a bunch! Now I don't know why it used to work before :/